# Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML5 - assumed 'ENT_HTML5'

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to create a simple method which accepts the parameters for htmlspecialchars. Although I am getting PHP notice:

> Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML5 - assumed 'ENT_HTML5'

1. Any ideas what could be causing this?

/**

```
 * Encode string.
 *
 * @param array/string $value
 * @param string $param
 * @return string
 */
protected function escape($mixed, $params) {

    $defaults = array('flags' => ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'charset' => 'UTF-8');
    $params = array_merge($defaults, $params);

    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = $this->escape($value, $params['flags'], $params['charset']);
        }
    } elseif (is_string($mixed)) {
        $mixed = htmlspecialchars($mixed, $params['flags'], $params['charset']);
    }

    return $mixed;
}
```

1. If I change: `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5` into: `ENT_QUOTES`, I get a different error

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string
>   given

**UPDATE**

I am using PHP 5.3 so this is the reason for the HTML5 error. If I change `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5` to `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401` I get the same sort of error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML401 - assumed 'ENT_HTML401'

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? ENT_HTML5 is for php 5.4 and up...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ENT_HTML5, ENT_HTML401, and some others were added in PHP version 5.4 [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). For earlier versions those constants are undefined, and PHP will automatically assume that undefined constants are programming "slips" and convert them to strings.