# PHP: Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML5 - assumed 'ENT_HTML5'

Tags: php, html, ubuntu, azure

I'm getting the error:

```
Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML5 - assumed 'ENT_HTML5' in /blahblahpath/application/models/Post.php on line 12
```

in a simple model that deals with some `POST` input in a forum app. The line that triggers this is as such:

```
$this->set_attribute('body', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($body), ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_HTML5));
```

Very simple.. I'm wondering if this is a server error because I just migrated to a new server and only encounter the problem there. No idea where to start and Googling hasn't yielded much. Using Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (the Windows Azure version) and PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT\_HTML5 - assumed 'ENT\_HTML5'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523282/notice-use-of-undefined-constant-ent-html5-assumed-ent-html5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [manual](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), you will notice that `ENT_HTML5` was added in version 5.4.0.

> 5.4.0  The constants ENT_SUBSTITUTE, ENT_DISALLOWED, ENT_HTML401, ENT_XML1, ENT_XHTML and ENT_HTML5 were added.

You will need to either upgrade PHP or not use any unsupported constants.

Comment: Ah, so looks like I downgraded PHP versions when I switched environments. D'oh!